# Problemas al visualizar datos en JTable

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist, jtable

Buenas tardes,

Tengo el siguiente problema y es que quiero visualizar todos los datos de un arrayList de tipo Contador, que es un objeto que he creado, y no se como añadir todos los contadores a esa tabla por que solo he logrado insertar 1.

## La clase principal es la siguiente

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

   ArrayList<Contador> contadores = new ArrayList<Contador>();
   contadores.add(new Contador("P44152F", "10:00:00", "21/03/2017", 100.00));
   contadores.add(new Contador("R41525R", "11:00:00", "22/03/2017", 99.00));

   GroupableHeaderExample frame = new GroupableHeaderExample(contadores);
   frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ) {
       System.exit(0);
     }
   });
   frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

## Código de la clase GroupableTableHeaderExample

```
public class GroupableHeaderExample extends JFrame {
public GroupableHeaderExample(ArrayList<Contador> contadores) {
super( "Tabla Ejemplos Header" );
JTable table = null;
//Se crea el vector para almacenar todo el array
Vector <Contador> datos = new Vector();
for(int i=0;i<contadores.size();i++){
    datos.addElement(contadores.get(i));
}

//Se crea el modelo de la cabecera
DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
for(int i=0;i<datos.size();i++){
    dm.setDataVector(
    new Object[][]{{datos.get(i).getFecha(),datos.get(i).getLectura(),"0"}},
    new Object[]{"Fecha","Lectura","Consumo"});

    //Creación de la tabla con el modelo de cabecera principal
    table = new JTable( dm ) {
      protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
          return new GroupableTableHeader(columnModel);
      }
    };

    //Se crea un segundo modelo
    TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();//Se coge el modelo del header principal
    ColumnGroup contador = new ColumnGroup(datos.get(i).getSerialNumber());//Se crea un grupo
    contador.add(cm.getColumn(1));
    contador.add(cm.getColumn(2));
    GroupableTableHeader header = (GroupableTableHeader)table.getTableHeader();
    header.addColumnGroup(contador);
}


JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
getContentPane().add( scroll );
setSize( 400, 120 ); 
}
}
```

El resultado que tengo de momento es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como comentaba antes solo me muestra 1 contador, y tengo dos en el arrayList, y no encuentro la manera de meter los dos.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a organizar de manera correcta el código para que salieran todos los elementos del arrayList?

Si alguién puede echarme una mano sería de gran ayuda.
Gracias de Antemano

Comment: Creo que por cada vuelta que da el ciclo esta modificando lo que ingresas a la tabla en el `DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();`

Comment: Ya eso ya me di cuenta yo antes, pero es que no se como solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Alguien me podría ayudar a organizar de manera correcta el código para que salieran todos los elementos del arrayList?

Comment: intenta sacando el `table = new JTable( dm )` del ciclo

Comment: Ya está más o menos ya lo he podido solucionar